# C# Как перекодировать текст \uNNNNNN в кириллицу

Tags: c#, кодировка

Устал уже биться над проблемой, поиск в интернет не дал результата.
Имеется Basic авторизация веб-апи. Нужно считать логин и пароль пользователя, чтобы использовать их для дальнейших запросов к другому сервису.

Использую функцию:

```
public JObject GetAuthorizationData()
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject(new JProperty("Username", ""), new JProperty("Password", ""), new JProperty("AuthorizationString", ""), new JProperty("isAutorized", false));
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        string authHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
        {
            obj["AuthorizationString"] = authHeader;
            obj["isAutorized"] = true;

            string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
            System.Text.Encoding w1251 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
            byte[] Fr64 = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword);
            string usernamePassword = w1251.GetString(Fr64);
            int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');

            obj["Username"] = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
            obj["Password"] = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Если логин и пароль на латиннице - все Ок, Но если на кириллице, то для "Иванов Иван" на выходе получаю "\u001820=>2 \u001820=".
Массив Fr64: 24 50 48 61 62 50 32 24 50 48 61 58 24 50 48 61 62 50 32 24 50 48 61
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы уверены, что данные приходят в кодировке 1251? Есть версия, что там utf-8. Да и в вообще, следует использовать юникод, чтобы пользователи любой язык могли использовать.

Comment: Для вашего примера массива Fr64, что должно получится?

Comment: Пробовал вместо 1251 подставлять UTF-8 - результат тот же.

Comment: Если сделать obj["Username"].ToString().ToCharArray() то получим массив:
24 '\u0018', 50 '2', 48 '0', 61 '=', 62 '>', 50 '2', 32 ' ', 24 '\u0018', 50 '2', 48 '0', 61 '='

Comment: Очень сложно понять, что вы хотите. В примере в вопросе у вас массив Fr64. Ок. Дальше в комментах у вас откуда-то \u0018 появляется, но 18 нет в исходном примере. Что у вас есть, и что должно получится не понятно

Comment: Я привел информацию из отладки. Массив Fr64 мы получаем после Convert.FromBase64String. Далее, когда мы берем GetString из этого массива, получаем строку., которую делим на Username и Password. Если для полученного Username сделать ToCharArray(), то получится массив, который дан в комментарии. Информация в данном случае была дана исключительно для понимания того, что происходит в процессе преобразования.